# How do you tell OpenVPN to run on startup?

Tags: debian, systemd, openvpn

I've done these exact same steps on two Ubuntu computers and it works just fine. I copied the exact same `foo.conf` file (along with a corresponding auth.txt file) into `/etc/openvpn/` and it works if I manually enter `service openvpn start`. But I can't get it to work on startup. I don't remember having a problem before. It just worked.

`/var/log/openvpn` is empty. `/etc/default/openvpn` matches the working computer (AUTOSTART="all" is commented so it should use all by default).

It's not starting the VPN after a reboot though.

Answer (score 1):

[Found an answer](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23085/how-to-start-openvpn-service-at-boot-time/?answer=23611#post-id-23611).

Replace <server> with the name of your configuration file.

```
sudo systemctl enable <server>.service
sudo systemctl start <server>.service
```

So for `/etc/openvpn/foo.conf` it would be

```
sudo systemctl enable foo.service
sudo systemctl start foo.service
```

Comment: This looks wrong to me... It will only work if there is a foo.service, created by you (which is what the answer at askfedora suggests) or by a generator of some kind... Do you already have a openvpn.service or perhaps openvpn@.service on your system? Please post which distribution version you're using (Debian Stretch?) and confirm which version of OpenVPN package you have around... If you can find the systemd services for OpenVPN their contents are also helpful here.

Comment: In my question I state that I already have a foo.conf file. After copying that to /etc/openvpn/ (along with a auth.txt file that foo.conf uses for the username and password) I ran the above command and restarted and it worked.

Comment: Well, I meant there needs to be a <b>foo.service</b> file too, for that to work... It's possible your distro is shipping a generator to create them on demand from the .conf files... (The answer in askfedora you linked to was instructing creating that file first.) I think that's not a great approach, using a service template (openvpn@.service) would be better, IMHO. Anyways, glad you found a solution to your issue.

Comment: oh, you're right. I just checked and there is no `/etc/systemd/system/<anything-relevant>.service`. idk. i'm not looking a gift horse in the mouth.

Comment: If it's a generator, it would be in `/run/systemd/system/` instead... Do you have any `openvpn.service` or `openvpn@.service` anywhere? Most probably in `/lib/systemd/system`... If you do, you can probably use them to start your VPN on boot...

Comment: Yep. `/run/systemd/system` is empty. But `/lib/systemd/system` does have `openvpn-client@.service`, `openvpn-server@.service`, `openvpn.service`, and `openvpn@.service`. Nice. Thanks!